# How to create a vertical carousel/ticker with dynamically created pagination thumbs

Tags: jquery, pagination, carousel, ticker, caroufredsel

> NOTE: Although I'm using CarouFredSel right now, I don't have any preference for a specific plugin.. I'm only interested in accomplishing the goal of the task,.. so if you have suggestions, please make a comment ! :D Thanks

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have boxes that contain dynamically created HTML content for which I need to:

**1)** provide a vertical (upward) carousel/ticker effect of the content, ONLY if there are more than 4 items loaded into the box.

**2)** If there are > 4 items, start the carousel/ticker, allow for pause on mouseover, resume on mouseout and provide navigation to change directions (up/down) or to step forward/backward per item in the carousel

**3)** There is a div at the bottom of each box. If the box has > 4 items, then I need to run through each item, get the source for an image within it (img.bimage) and build a pagination of thumbs within that div at the bottom of the box. This should allow the user to click a thumb and have the list scroll to it.

**Here is a working example of where we are so far:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/revive/jZMhE/

`(note, the pagination callback is commented out of the JS, but that is what the pagination should look like)`

Please let me know if you have suggestions on how to accomplish these things with CarouFredSel ***OR ANOTHER Plugin or function***.. We're not stuck on using one thing or another.. we're stuck on making it work :D

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some `JS` crunching and hair pulling.. I decided to forego the function within CarouFredSel and used this example: http://jsfiddle.net/revive/jZMhE/